# View not updating as scope value update

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to hide and show start/stop button(toggle) and also load button status wise first time in `ng-repeat`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="panel panel-warning" ng-repeat="msg in message">
        <button type="button" ng-show="{{msg.Status}} == 1" ng-click="StopSend(msg.msgkey)" class="start-sending btn btn-info btn-fill btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Resume sending the message">
            <span><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></span>
            Stop sending
        </button>
        <button type="button" ng-show="{{msg.Status}} == 0" ng-click="StartSend(msg.msgkey)" class="start-sending btn btn-info btn-fill btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Resume sending the message">
            <span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
            Start sending
        </button>
  <div />
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.StartSend = function (mkey) {
    //Start Sending
    DataTransaction.StopSend(mkey,1).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);//gets update value to db
    })
    .catch(function errorCallback(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

$scope.StopSend = function (mkey) {

    //Stop Sending
    DataTransaction.StopSend(mkey,0).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);/gets update value to db
    })
    .catch(function errorCallback(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

}

$scope.Getmessages = function() {
    DataTransaction.GetMessage(Instaid).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.message = response.data;

    })
    .catch(function errorCallback(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [1373110](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20684996/1373110).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="panel panel-warning" ng-repeat="msg in message">
        <button type="button" ng-click="Send(msg.msgkey, msg)" class="start-sending btn btn-info btn-fill btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Resume sending the message">
            <span><i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-play': msg.Status == 0, 'fa-pause': msg.Status == 1}"></i></span>
            <span ng-bind-template="{{msg.Status == 1 ? 'Stop Sending' : 'Start Sending'}}">
        </button>
  <div />

$scope.StartSend = function (mkey, msg) {
    //Start Sending
    msg.Status = msg.Status == 1 ? 0 : 1
    DataTransaction.StopSend(mkey,msg.Status).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);//gets update value to db
    })
    .catch(function errorCallback(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: My mistake ng-bind-template="{{msg.Status == 1 ? 'Stop Sending' : 'Start Sending'}}" update ng-bind-template ( status variable is small letter and should be capital like Status). I've updated example

Comment: ng-class="{'fa-play': msg.Status == 0, 'fa-pause': msg.Status == 1}"

Comment: Yehh, Its work like a charm ! Thank you so much @Melzar

Comment: My pleasure - have fun :)